# Should application logging code always be in catch block

Tags: c#, logging, exception

Should application logging code always be in catch block?
Is it better for instance to check is object null in try block and if so log the exception or catch nullreference exception and log error(warning)

Comment: Depends on the context of the code block, and what exactly the intended purpose of the log is dont ya think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It will always* be a better practice to prevent an exception in the first place than to handle one after the fact.
- If a null reference is a real possibility, the code should already test for and appropriately handle this.
- Logging should be as disconnected from exception handling as possible.  Really, you need to log as much as possible and then let your application logger decide what's actually important.  (Use error levels - information, warning, error)  So yes, your `catch` blocks should log, but that should definitely not be the only place you do logging.

*I'm sure there's some edge-case scenario where this isn't true, but it's quite rare.

Answer (score 2):

It is always good to have logs which will help you to understand what is going on, how application behaves, to do proper tracking, monitoring and etc...but where to have it I think it depends from your application and context. For sure the exception details must be logged so you can check what is happening, but to log in catch block in finally block or somewhere else it depends from your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Always** is a strong word, Logging code should be where needed. In most cases there are categories of logging.

```
**INFO**: General application information 
**DEBUG**: Information that may be helpful if trying to debug using the log.
**ERROR**: Error information.
```

I'm sure there are other categories however as you can see, in the case of these 3, ERROR logging will probably only be in the catch block where as the other 2 can really be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's better doing so within the catch block, even if on the basis of readability alone. It's always better to separate error-handling from your other code.

Answer (score 0):

I think logging is a cross-cutting concern, so I'd put it in an aspect.  The more catch blocks you have, the more logging code you have to write.  If you can weave advice into exceptions you can write that logging code once and keep it in one place.